# Visual Studio SSIS Project - Script Task Build Error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ssis

I would like to learn developing SSIS packages on my personal computer. I am interested in writing C# scripts. I installed Visual Studio 2019 on Windows 10 Pro 64-bit with SSDT and also installed Integration Services Projects as an extension.

I opened a new Integration Services project, did not touch anything just created a Script Task in the Control Flow. Selected the language as C# and clicked Edit Script.

VS opens a new instance of itself where the C# script can be edited. Again before touching anything, I tried to Build the script and I get the following error:

```
Description:
Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\Vsta\10d65f335e71425ba94036412d88bdce_out'.

Path:
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\Vsta\SSIS_ST150\VstaoFH46KVGKkav0SoVwTnyOQ\Vstad9rJhrfNxUeKqqUuEmYPqw\

File:
mscorlib    

Line:
0
```

I ran Visual Studio as an administrator and my Windows username is simple like "George".

I am looking for a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downgrade (uninstall and install again) visual studio from version 16.9.0 to 16.8.2 and everything works like a charm now!

Answer (score 0):

Download : https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.SqlServerIntegrationServicesProjects
or the latest version of it