# Could not find a part of the path in 'C:\' at line 0

Tags: c#, ssis, script-task

I am stuck with an error on `Script Task` in `SSIS package`. I could found similar questions but they are different from my scenario.

Build the Script and which was failed with following error (for Error list please refer following image):

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error     Could not find a part of the path
> 'C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Temp\2\Vsta\166f3f6a0a3b4d2b9bce8275652e86c5_out'.
> ST_e39a74fadbb04a8088f3dcc732f67cf0   C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Temp\2\Vsta\SSIS_ST140\VstagyjdfDg98EOThQux2q_T5A\VstaFGRuzNpZdEeMuG1swXzy5g\mscorlib   0

**Error List:**

[image: Error from error list]

I can understand this error that `File not found in the path`. OK. I can change path, but it shows `line: 0`. When I click the error I have following notification.

**Message:**

[image]

So, now my questions are,

where this path is exist in the project?
how to resolve this error?

Note:

1. I am using following version VS Code.

> Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
> Version 16.9.1 VisualStudio.16.Release/16.9.1+31105.61 Microsoft .NET
> Framework Version 4.7.03062

2. File name `*_out` in error is changed for each time build.

Thanks,

Pugal.

Comment: I'd say this is impossible to answer without some sample code of your script task! Especially of the Main() method. Anyways, you wrote that the _out varies after each build - what are you passing as path to your statement? Is it a string you build somewhere else? As you mentioned, this points to a file not being found (or which is not accessible for the current user) - so maybe the path is simply faulty!?

Comment: For SSIS Script tasks, especially debugging a lot of times I will write it as a console app (much easier to debug, step through code, and just faster.  There is some work to convert it to SSIS script task (sometimes more than others depending on code) but the more complex code or finding issues, in console app much easier and errors are much more understandable.

Comment: Okay I will upload samples. But my main question, what is meant by `line 0`?

Comment: @Brad, I am beginner to `SSIS` and newbee to `Script Task`.. But Ok will try that using team's help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update**:
There is now fixed in Visual Studio 2019, But the fix is to install the latest version of Visual Studio for Applications.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.SqlServerIntegrationServicesProjects

> There is a regression in VS 2019 16.9 that will cause script task/component not work properly when editing script. VSTA team has released a new version to work around this issue. Please install latest version 3.12.1 to fix the issue, or you can keep on version 3.12 and manually download and install the latest version of VSTA 2019 [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58317).

**Old**:
As per below, this is broken in Visual Studio 2019 16.9

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.SqlServerIntegrationServicesProjects

> There is a regression in VS 2019 16.9 that will cause script task/component not work properly when editing script. Please do NOT upgrade to 16.9 currently. If you have already upgraded to 16.9, please rollback to 16.8 or earlier version if you are using script task/component.

So, try with the latest available 16.8.x version.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/history#installing-an-earlier-release

You could also vote for this item

https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/SSIS-script-task-do-not-build/1354064

> SSIS script task do not build

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Subbu, will downgrade to `16.8.x`.

Comment: Sorry for late response. Script task worked fine on `version 15.9.34`

Comment: Upgrading VS v16.10 also fixes the issue now.

Answer (score 2):

I also face with this problem. Downgrade visual studio to 16.8.2 help solve this problem!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66510806/visual-studio-ssis-project-script-task-build-error/66517251#66517251

Comment: Ohh. Thanks for the suggestion. I team met already try this on `version 15.9.34` no luck for us.

Comment: Worked fine on `version 15.9.34`.

Answer (score 2):

try to install this version of ssis

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.SqlServerIntegrationServicesProjects

Answer (score 2):

A workaround was posted on the VS marketplace:

> 1. Click “Edit Script” to open the project in VS
> 2. Right click on the project in solution explorer, and click “Open Folder in File Explorer”
> 3. In the file explorer, open the csproj or vbproj file with any text editor
> 4. Find the two element, change the value to .\bin\Debug\ and .\bin\Release\
>    separately, or you can simply remove them
> 5. Save the csproj or vbproj and reload the project
> 6. Now you can try to rebuild the project in VS

The instructions aren't super clear but I found that simply commenting out the `OutputPath` nodes in the two configuration `PropertyGroup`s did the trick.

For example:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <!-- <OutputPath>.\bin\Debug\</OutputPath> -->
    <EnableUnmanagedDebugging>false</EnableUnmanagedDebugging>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' ">
    <DebugSymbols>false</DebugSymbols>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <!-- <OutputPath>.\bin\Release\</OutputPath> -->
    <EnableUnmanagedDebugging>false</EnableUnmanagedDebugging>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: In my project, the values were already set to `.\bin\Debug\` etc. Removing/commenting them is the key, it seems. VS will then prompt you to reload the project. This is the right solution if you don't have control over your VS2019 version.